# PDF rendering slow, need help debugging with ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

We're switching over to a new PDF library and re-architecting.  We were taken by surprise when told by our print shop that the new files were much slower than the originals.  Each page is coming out at least 20% slower.

The pages consist of two images, lots of text, with lots of lines/boxes, and some shading behind text. The document is ~100pages long.

After some initial tinkering we've gotten the file size down, but confusingly the speed hasn't come back.  We've tried the usual tricks: right-sizing the images, eliminating custom fonts, and so on.

To demonstrate, I ran the PDF's through Ghostscript.  (The real printing situation adds a lot of variables.)  This was my test command:

```
gswin64c.exe -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o junk.pdf $_.FullName
```

Sure enough, the new files are slower.

```
File                    Time      Size
Original.pdf            4299ms    917k   < Good rendering time
Concatenated.pdf        7029ms   9953k
Singlefile.pdf          6049ms    566k
BuiltinFont.pdf         6680ms    496k
```

Is there some ghostscript-fu or other tooling I can use to figure out why this library is producing slow-to-render PDFs?

Comment: I'd rather not name the library as it's not commercial and that might be unfair to the maintainer.

Comment: FWIW -dPDFDEBUG will dump a complete transcript of what Ghostscript is doing, so you can see what it's up to at any moment. However... First things is that 7 seconds isn't really a long time. Second point would be that the PDF file is 10 times the size, so it's quite likely that a good chunk of time is spent just reading that data. The only likely reason for the file being so much larger is that the content has been rendered to an image. In which case there's likely nothing you can do about it. If you make an example file available I'll look at it.

Comment: I should probably note that this question will probably get closed, since it is technically off-topic.

Comment: Also, if you use the pdfwrite device, then Ghostscript isn't **rendering** the files at all, its creating a new PDF file.